# Subscription doesn't exists when using Set-AzureSubscription

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to run a powershell script against all VMs in an azure subscription.  I used AzureRunAsConnection to connect to the service principal.  Using Get-AzureVM gives an error that I haven't set the default Subscription.  When I try to set it using Select-AzureSubscription I am given an error message stating the subscription doesn't exist.  Here's what I am using in the runbook.

```
'''
$conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name 'AzureRunAsConnection'
Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $conn.TenantID -ApplicationID $conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $conn.CertificateThumbprint
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName *********
'''
```

The exact error message is:

```
'''
Select-AzureSubscription : The subscription name ***** doesn't exist.
Parameter name: id
At line:3 char:1
+ Select-AzureSubscription -Current -SubscriptionName "******** ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Select-AzureSubscription], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.SelectAzureSubscriptionCommand
'''
```

What am I doing wrong to keep getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@david is right you are confusing the commands, Classic (Azure) vs AzureRM.

If the goal is to get VM in subscripts below are sample code for Calssic and AzureRM

Classic

```
$ConnectionAssetName = "AzureClassicRunAsConnection"
$connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionAssetName        
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $ConnectionAssetName
$CertificateAssetName = $Conn.CertificateAssetName
$AzureCert = Get-AutomationCertificate -Name $CertificateAssetName
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $Conn.SubscriptionName -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID -Certificate $AzureCert 
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID
Get-AzureVM
```

AzureRM

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
$servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         
Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
Get-AzureRMVM
```

Also keep in mind that connections are tied to a subscription so for AzureRM you do not needed to `select` a subscription.  If you want to `select` one (`Select-AzureRmSubscription`) it should be the same as the one in the connection properties.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv5rf.png]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  You guys were right.  I was confusing myself about the commands.

Answer (score 2):

There are three generations of Azure powershell modules, "Azure", "AzureRM", and "AZ".  Looks like you've got multiple installed.  Try

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription
```

instead.